# How to send email notification when assigning task to resources in project server 2013 web app?

Tags: ms-project-2013, project-server

I use Project server 2013 and I created a Project web app site.

I created an enterprise project and entered the team data.

Now I am able to assign tasks to resources.

What I want is that the team member is notified by email if when I assign a task to that team member.

[image]

In the screen shot you can see that I have assigned tasks to users.
 You can see **Liza Naeem** which is an active directory user and has an email.

How can I notify Liza Naeem by email using a Project automatism that this task was assigned to him.

Comment: I don't use Project Server, but a quick search turned up:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635886.aspx

Comment: Have you tried putting email addresses in resource sheet for the team members to whom you are assigning the task. Also try putting the publish column and send updates

Comment: Thank you for your post. I did the same actions, but alerts/notifications about tasks' assignments don't send to resources. I also enabled alerts/notifications for each resources too. Emails from Workflows work, but alerts/notifications don't. Do you know what may be a reason? Thank you!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12942)

Comment: For Project Server 2016 the steps have been changed, check this [Project Server 2016: Missing Alerts and Reminders Settings](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/09/23/missing-alerts-and-reminders-in-project-server-2016/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on the internet and Microsoft site

I solved my problem

1- Go to SharePoint Central administration page click on under general application settings

click on PWA settings Manage, once the page is opened under operational policies 
click on alerts and reminders
set your SMTP mail server and email address it will work.

Comment: this is very usefull i want to connect you

Comment: For Project Server 2016 the steps have been changed, check this [Project Server 2016: Missing Alerts and Reminders Settings](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/09/23/missing-alerts-and-reminders-in-project-server-2016/)