# Project Server 2016 doesn't send task assignment alerts to resources

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I have SharePoint Server 2016 and Project Server 2016.

I turned on notification sending in Central Administration and for each resources, but resources don't receive any alerts/notifications after the resource is assigned to a project task.

I did settings according these links, but they don't help:

[How to send email notification when assigning task to resources in project server 2013 web app](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/how-to-send-email-notification-when-assigning-task-to-resources-in-project-serve)

[Configuring e-mail notifications and reminders in Project Web App](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh767487%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Alerts and Reminders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635886.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In **Project Server 2016**, the steps to configure [**Alerts and Reminders**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-alerts-and-reminders-in-project-server-2016/) have been changed and the [**Alerts and Reminders**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-alerts-and-reminders-in-project-server-2016/) option is now not located in `Central Administration` below `Operational Policies` as it was in Project Server 2013.

**To configure Alerts and Reminders, you should**

- Configure outgoing e-mail settings in SharePoint Server 2016.
- Configure Email Settings in Project Server 2016: Turn on notifications.
- Manage My Alerts and Reminders in Personal Settings

For the detail steps, check **[Project Server 2016: Missing Alerts and Reminders Settings.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-alerts-and-reminders-in-project-server-2016/)**